# Counting the number of nodes containing data at a specific level - nTree

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

I have an nTree (n-dimensions) and I want to calculate the number of nodes containing data points at a particular depth. Here is the tree structure and the function that I am trying to use:

```
class nTree:

    def initialize(self, hypercube_coordinates, depth=0):
        self.data = [] #holds the data - this tells if the node is empty or not
        self.children = [] 
        self.depth = depth
        self.hypercube = hypercube #coordinates 

    #a bit inefficient since we are theoretically visiting each node
    #can be optimized later
    def count_nodes_at_level(self, depth):
        count = 0
        for child in self.children:
            if child.depth == depth:
                count += child.count_nodes_at_level(self.depth)
            else:
                child.count_nodes_at_level(depth)
        return count
```

I am aware that my method is a bit inefficient but I want it to work at first, then I can optimize it. I have read a different post on this matter and my method is quite similar to the other posts' one, but it does not work for an nTree. In my case, I have 64 children/parent. Also, I am not sure if any of the PreOrder, PostOrder, InOrder or BreadthFirst traversals will work since I cannot reference a left or right sub child. Any suggestions for improving/making the method work?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. For anyone looking for a solution here is the method:

```
#countNodesAtLevel - returns the number of non-empty nodes at a given level
#Parameters:
#    depth - depth at which we are counting

def _countNodesAtLevel(self, depth, count=0):

    #root level = 0, return only 1 for the data
    if depth == 0 and self.data:
        return 1
    else:
        for child in self.children:
            if child.depth == depth and child.data:
                count+=1
                count+=child.countNodesAtLevel(depth)
            else:
                count+=child.countNodesAtLevel(depth)
    return count

#USER FUNCTION
#countNodesAtLevel - returns the number of non-empty nodes at a given level
def countNodesAtLevel(self, depth):
    count = self._countNodesAtLevel(depth)
    print(count)
```

This method uses a depth first traversal model so it checks every node in the tree. I am sure there are better ways to do this in less than O(n).